# Android ListView Update thread on each of its item

Tags: android

My ListView contains two TextViews. One of them is showing a number and this number is incremented till a fixed value(Lets say 100) in every one second. For example if a row of ListView has the number 5 then it will increased 6,7,8....100 and other item of this listview have 13 then it will increased like 14,15,16...100.

So how and when start and stop a thread for each row that will update numbers for every row.I think I have to start a thread from BaseAdapter.getView() but the problem is when the ListItem is updated then how to handle this situation.

Comment: I am not able to implement it

Comment: You're most likely looking for a `Handler` rather than threads, which have a lot of overhead. Threads will also cause problems because you can't update views from another thread than the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, I know what you say but how to implement it using handler

Comment: Try using a timer, started within your activity, to update the data that is attached to the ListView's adapter at the required interval (say once per second). When that completes, post a call to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on the UI thread using a Handler as mentioned by Dalmas.